# How to execute sybase stored procedure in SQL Developer with input and out put params?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sybase, plsqldeveloper

I am working on a new Database in Sybase. I am not sure how to run sybase stored procedures from SQL Developer. I have used SQL developer before with Oracle.

my stored procedure look like this. IT is working stored procedure.

```
create proc stored_proc_name @string_input varchar(20)
as
declare
@ temp_string varchar(20)
select @temp_string from table where conduction
return 0
fail:
....

exec db_schema..stored_proc_name 'string_input'
```

Output

```
db_schema..stored_proc_name 'string_input' succeeded.
```

ITs not printing the actual output. 
Please help me fix my issue.

Comment: I am not allowed to use any other non approved softwares

Comment: your synthax for sybase is wrong

Comment: My example stored proc syntax is wrong. I am trying to run working stored proc in my test env

Comment: If you want useful help you need to indicate everything you tried to eliminate various possible reasons for the problem. Without thay there can only be guessing.

Comment: Your table may have zero qualifying rows?

Comment: Its returning results. It has 10 rows in resultset.

Comment: How is [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) related to the question?